# Cubes OLAP PYTHON framework how to order date extract from database?

Tags: olap, cubes

I get the date from my database (PostgreSQL):

```
mapping{
    "logged_at.hour": {"column":"logged_at", "extract":"hour"},
    "logged_at.month": {"column":"logged_at", "extract":"month"},
    "logged_at.day": {"column":"logged_at", "extract":"day"},
}
```

But when I use them they are not sorted:

```
examples:
hour:1,3,2,9,7,5
what i want is :1,2,3,5,7,9
what can i do .thanks
```

Comment: Have you solved it? I am also struggling in this problem.